# How to programmatically set alignment of databound GridView?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

Here is my code:

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
gv.DataSource = listOfEntities;
gv.DataBind();

// set alignment for description column
gv.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
```

On the last line I get **index was out of range** error, and indeed if I inspect the GridView there's no columns yet. The Entity I am binding has 2 properties and they get rendered OK if I don't try to align them.

Is there a way to do this without having to dynamically assign a delegate to the DataBoundEvent of the gridview?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got around it for now:

```
gv.CssClass = "left-aligned-text";
```

and

```
table.left-aligned-text td
{
   text-align: left;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OR

```
Protected Sub mygridview_Databound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mygridview.DataBound

    Dim gv As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
    gv.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
    gv.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left
    gv.FooterStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left

End Sub
```